# c3 bar chart label not showing

Tags: jquery, charts, c3.js

I have a c3 chart script as follows

```
            data: {
            x : 'x',
            columns: [
                ['Operations',51,6],
                ['x','Local','Local & Overseas'],
            ],
            type: 'bar'
```

My output is not showing as desired it trims word "Local &" Please refer following screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone help me to customise the c3 chart code to make "Local & Overseas" to show correctly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a suitable value in your c3 configuration for 'padding' -->

https://c3js.org/samples/options_padding.html